# C++/CLI passing additional arguments to event handling method

Tags: event-handling, c++-cli

I'm trying to write a C++/CLI forms application that creates a lot of buttons at runtime: I have a vector of strings and for each string a button is being created:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
/*
    string being initialized with values from file
*/
for ( std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = heroes.begin(); it != heroes.end(); ++it ) {
    Button ^ button = gcnew Button;
    /*
        button being customized depending on the string
    */
    buttonPannel->Controls->Add(button);
}
```

Now what I want to do is add an event handler for each button in a way that the string used to customize the button would be passed to handling method.

In c# I would have written something like

```
button->Click += new EventHandler((sender, args) => button_Click(s, e, *it));
```

How do I achieve this in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the exact equivalent of your C# code, but I'd rather make use of an existing property on the [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) class to hold the extra data you need.

In this case, the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property seems appropriate: its purpose is to hold any extra data you need that is closely associated with the control, so this seems on-point for your string that drives the program logic. (You may need to make it a managed `String^` object, rather than a `std::string`, but that's an easy conversion.)

```
void Form1::CreateButtons()
{
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = heroes.begin(); it != heroes.end(); ++it)
    {
        Button ^ button = gcnew Button;

        button->Tag = marshal_as<String^>(*it);

        button->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::button_Click);

        buttonPanel->Controls->Add(button);
    }
}

void Form1::button_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    Control^ senderControl = dynamic_cast<Control^>(sender);
    String^ heroName = nullptr;
    if(senderControl != nullptr)
        heroName = dynamic_cast<String^>(senderControl->Tag);

    if(heroName == nullptr)
    {
        // Something went wrong. Bail out.
        return;
    }    

    // ...
}
```

If you really do want to do the equivalent of your C# code: Your C# lambda is doing variable capture on the `it` variable. We can do variable capture in C++/CLI, it's just a lot more manual.

(Note: Your C# example is capturing the iterator, not the string, not sure if that's what was intended. I wrote this to capture the string object instead.)

```
ref class EventHandlerStringCapture
{
public:
    EventHandlerStringCapture(std::string str,
        Action<Object^, EventArgs^, std::string>^ handler)
    {
        this->str = str;
        this->handler = handler;
    }

    void eventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        this->handler(sender, e, this->str);
    }

private:
    std::string str;
    Func<Object^, EventArgs^, std::string>^ handler;
}

void Form1::CreateButtons()
{
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = heroes.begin(); it != heroes.end(); ++it)
    {
        Button ^ button = gcnew Button;

        // The variable to capture.        
        std::string str = *it;
        // The actual event handler: a method in the current class.
        Action<Object^, EventArgs^, std::string>^ actualHandler = 
            gcnew Action<Object^, EventArgs^, std::string>(this, &Form1::button_Click);

        // Pass both the variable to capture and the 
        // actual event handler to a helper object.
        EventHandlerStringCapture^ ehsc = 
            gcnew EventHandlerStringCapture(str, actualHandler);

        // Grab the two-parameter event handler from the helper object, 
        // and make that the click handler.
        button->Click += 
            gcnew EventHandler(ehsc, &EventHandlerStringCapture::eventHandler);

        buttonPanel->Controls->Add(button);
    }
}

void Form1::button_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e, std::string heroName)
{
    // ...
}
```

(Note: I'm not at a compiler, so there may be syntax errors.)

Obviously, using an existing property on the button object is simpler, but that's the C++/CLI equivalent to what the C# compiler does behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after I changed all of the std::string to String ^ and Func to Action (Func would return string rather than having it as an argument).

Comment: Thanks for the Action correction. I also added an example using the Tag property of the button. I think you'll find the Tag implementation simpler.